# Where Can I find Social Sites Evaluation Data?

Tags: dataset, data-dump

I am working on evaluation methods in online social communities, and I need real-word data to apply my algorithms on. What I exactly need is some records that shows the votes that users have given to each other in a social network, forum, Q&A community, etc. I need VoterID, VoteeID, Time and Vote Value. I downloaded a datadump of stackoverflow and extracted data from them. The problem here is that the votes files does not contain voterID (exepting for VoteTypeID=5).
Can anyone help me find such a dataset?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself some very good resources here :
http://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html
in the web site of SNAP project in Stanford university.

Maybe useful to others

Answer (score 0):

```
<aws:UsageStatistics>
  <aws:UsageStatistic>
<aws:PageViews>
      <aws:PerMillion>
        <aws:Value>54,074</aws:Value>
        <aws:Delta>+4.094%</aws:Delta>
      </aws:PerMillion>
      <aws:Rank>
        <aws:Value>2</aws:Value>
        <aws:Delta>1</aws:Delta>
      </aws:Rank>
      <aws:PerUser>
        <aws:Value>12.31</aws:Value>
        <aws:Delta>-0.97%</aws:Delta>
      </aws:PerUser>
    </aws:PageViews>
</aws:UsageStatistic>
  <aws:UsageStatistic>
```

OR you can find out on Stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660607/how-to-calculate-the-site-value)

Comment: Hi Sb, I have my won algorithms and I need the row data (datasets) to apply my algorithms and calculate for example community-wide reputation of a user in a community.